# Null pointer exception while sending data from service to activity using intent

Tags: java, android

I am sending data from Service Class to Main Activity using Bundle but its sending null.

**Service Class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LocationService.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("final_address", addressText);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Main Activity**

```
Intent intentReceived = getIntent();
Bundle b = intentReceived.getExtras();
address = b.getString("final_address");
```

I also tried sending it through broadcasting messages but it failed too.See below:

**Service Class**

```
public static final String ADDRESSIDENTIFY = "address_identify";
public static final String ADDRESS_PATH = "address_path";

Intent intent = new Intent(ADDRESSIDENTIFY);
intent.putExtra(ADDRESS_PATH, addressText);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Main Activity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            address = bundle.getString(LocationService.ADDRESS_PATH);

        }
    }
};
```

and calling this in main activity on create

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ADDRESSIDENTIFY));
```

I have declared service in manifest too.

```
<service
  android:name="com.gampzz.bhojannearby.LocationService"
  android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

What should i do..Where am I wrong??

Comment: share log cat crash report

Comment: you need `broadcast receiver` to get data from `service` to `activity` , also declare your `receiver` in the manifest!

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif send me a link to do so.

Comment: have a look there 

http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/11/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect it's working in my case. Check with mine if you are missing something. Are you defining your `service` inside `application` in **manifest**?

**Service Class**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    public static final String ADDRESSIDENTIFY = "address_identify";
    public static final String ADDRESS_PATH = "address_path";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        Log.e("service", "oncreate");


        Intent intent = new Intent(ADDRESSIDENTIFY);
        intent.putExtra(ADDRESS_PATH, "hello");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String address;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ADDRESSIDENTIFY));

        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                address = bundle.getString(LocationService.ADDRESS_PATH);
                System.out.println("val"+ " = "+ address);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and **mainfest**

```
 ...
    <service android:name=".LocationService"
             android:enabled="true"/>

</application>
```

Comment: I used 8th article of that link to send data as i told you in my question above. Please suggest me a better article i want to send data from service class to activity class.

Comment: thanks sir but i solved the problem doing something else.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No need to send broadcast Using LocalBroadcastManager like this:

```
private LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcastManger;
```

Put this on `onCreate()` of the servcie

```
mBroadcastManger = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
```

Send broadcast using intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ADDRESSIDENTIFY);
intent.putExtra(ADDRESS_PATH, addressText);
mBroadcastManger.sendBroadcast(mIntent);
```